# Use a VPN only for some specific routes

Tags: vpn, routing

I want to use a VPN only for some specific routes (so that the default route is not on the VPN).

So in the Add VPN dialog I selected the "Use this connection only for resources on its network" (this doesn't change the default route) and then I added some subnetworks that I want to route to the VPN.

However, I'm not sure which gateway should I set here, as this is the VPN's gateway address, and it's dynamic (from DHCP).

[image: Add VPN dialog]

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: @brauliobo unfortunately not

Comment: finally managed to make it work and added an answer. it is focused on Ubuntu but with some changes it will work

Answer (score 1):

I'm using FreshTomato here. I managed to only redirect 3 destination IPs to the VPN.

Below is the OpenVPN custom configuration:

```
allow-pull-fqdn
route-nopull
script-security 2
up /opt/openvpn-routes.sh
```

Then the script mentioned above:

```bash
root@router:/tmp/home/root# cat /opt/openvpn-routes.sh 
#!/bin/sh
ip route add 204.11.51.251/32  dev tun11 # www.linksysinfo.org
ip route add 201.54.48.99/32   dev tun11 # www12.senado.leg.br
ip route add 34.160.111.145/32 dev tun11 # ifconfig.me
```

For Ubuntu you can add custom configuration with the following command:

```
sudo nmcli connection modify vpnu-br +vpn.data key=value
```

The /opt mount point was set up following the instructions from https://github.com/Entware/Entware/wiki/Install-on-TomatoUSB-and-FreshTomato